# Working with arrays inside javascript objects and using the array values dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have this code. 
I want to set objects dynamically with the value of an array inside other object

```
var object1 = {repetidos : {}};
var object2 = {nombre: 'Example', precio: 'Example 2', etc...};

//Object with the array
var carga = {
    repetidos : ['nombre','precio']
}

// custom function to set objects... I don't want to return nothing
cargaDatos(object1,object2,carga);

// Here is the function that i'm trying to code
cargaDatos = function(object1,object2,carga){

    // what can i do here?. I have tried to use for loops
    for(var key in carga){
        for(var key2 in key){
           //Here I have tried many things
        }
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// I want set something like this inside the function
object1.repetidos.nombre = object2.nombre;  // nombre is variable
object1.repetidos.precio = object2.precio;  // precio is variable
etc ....
```

What can I do to set the objects like above with variable values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `[]` notation of objects.

```js
var object1 = {
  repetidos: {}
};
var object2 = {
  nombre: 'Example',
  precio: 'Example 2'
};

//Object with the array
var carga = {
  repetidos: ['nombre', 'precio']
};

// Here is the function that i'm trying to code
var cargaDatos = function(object1, object2, carga) {
  // what can i do here?. I have tried to use for loops
  for (var key in carga) {
    for (var key2 in carga[key]) {
      // since carga[key] is an array key2 refers to the index
      var actualKey2 = carga[key][key2];
      object1[key][actualKey2] = object2[actualKey2];
    }
  }
}

// custom function to set objects... I don't want to return nothing
cargaDatos(object1, object2, carga);

//test
console.log(object1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bracket notation to dynamically access the objects elements:

```
cargaDatos(object1,object2,carga);

function cargaDatos(object1,object2,carga){
    for(var key in carga){
        for(var key2 in key){
           object1[key][carga[key][key2]] = object2[carga[key][key2]];
        }
    }
}
console.log(object1);
```

Also note, that i changed `var cargaDatos = function....` to `function cargaDatos` because otherwise you need to declare `var cargaDatos` before you use it. If you just use `function cargaDatos` it doesn't matter if you declare it before or after you use it.

NOTE: if you want to dynamically fill the entire `object1` you have to ensure that the element `key` exists on `object1`:

```
for(var key in carga){
    for(var key2 in key){
       if(!object1[key])object1[key] = {};
       object1[key][carga[key][key2]] = object2[carga[key][key2]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Markai. It worked too, but I have a meteor exception. Now I'm looking for why. Thanks for the explanation about function declarations

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to understand is you can access object properties with dynamic keys by `obj[key]`. To traverse the array you can also use foreach..

```
cargaDatos = function(object1,object2,carga){
    for(var key in carga){
        carga[key].forEach(function(x){
            object1[key][x] = object2[x];
        });
    }
}
```